# You don't have 'phantomjs' installed

Tags: node.js, path, phantomjs

I do have PhantomJS installed, but I get the error (you don't have 'phantomjs' installed) when I run my Node.js code:

```
var modules = '/home/engine/node_modules/';

var path = require('path');
var childProcess = require('child_process');
var phantom = require(modules+'phantom');
var binPath = phantom.path;

phantom.create(function(browser){ // Error happens here I think because the module is found
    // browser.createPage(function (page){});
});
```

If in console.log binPath I get undefined.

But in PuTTY, if I:

```
cd ~/phantomjs/
[root@engine phantomjs]# bin/phantomjs
phantomjs>
```

Have I installed it in the wrong place?

Comment: Is it in the PATH variable?

Comment: How did you installed it ? npm install -g phantomjs ?

Comment: the node module is found fine, but the phantomjs bin thing is not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load your global PhantomJS module and not the local.

Loading the local module prevents you application from locating the runnable bin:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
```

Plus, adding utnas comment:

> Remove **var modules = '/home/engine/node_modules/';**. It's not useful. Node.js knows where to find modules.

Mixing both parts of the answer to a logical rule, Node.js will always first load the module from the global installed modules if it exists. You force it to load the local one and that prevents it from finding the bin.

Comment: Remove var modules = '/home/engine/node_modules/'; is not useful. Node knows where to find modules

Answer (score 4):

I was also getting this error at my macOS, so this command did the trick.

```
brew install phantomjs
```

edit:
phantomjs was moved to Cask. So in 2019 run:

```
brew cask install phantomjs
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer in this case was not really a solution. The error message `You don't have 'phantomjs' installed` is an internal error from the [phantomjs-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom) module. I ran into this error myself, and I managed to fix it like this:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

var options = {
        path: '/usr/local/bin/'
};

phantom.create(function (ph) {
    ph.createPage(function (page) {
        page.open("http://www.google.com", function (status) {
            console.log("opened google? ", status);
            page.evaluate(function () { return document.title; }, function (result) {
                console.log('Page title is ' + result);
                ph.exit();
            });
        });
    });
}, options);
```

Notice the `options` being passed to the `phantom.create()` method. The `path` option should be the full path to the directory that contains your phantomjs binary.

Answer (score 0):

But if you are on Windows, you can try some thing like this:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

phantom.create(function (ph) {
  ph.createPage(function (page) {
     page.open("http://www.google.com", function (status) {
        console.log("opened google? ", status);
        page.evaluate(function () { return document.title; }, function  (result) {
            console.log('Page title is ' + result);
            ph.exit();
          });
        });
     });
    }, {
    dnodeOpts: {
       weak: false
    }
});
```